Do the arm movements of the woman in 73 Yards mean anything?
Throughout the episode, the figure of the old woman is looping a series of movements.


Is this some sort of sign language, or have any other standard meaning, or has been explained by the production team?

I'm pretty sure that's the Macarena.

From the imdb Trivia page for this episode:

In reality, the choreographed movements and words Hilary Hobson mouthed on camera - not the dialogue the 73 Yard Woman says to people to make them run, which Russell T. Davies is happy to leave to viewer's imaginations - went along the lines of "Bless you, thank you so much (shrug); that's so kind of you, when you gave me that little thing (circular hand movement), it was just so precious (hands to heart); how am I ever going to repay you? (big shrug) But we'll think of something."

Source -

BBC Doctor Who Unleashed (BBC iPlayer - link may not be accessible in all markets)
BBC YouTube Channel - for everyone else


Here it is straight from the actress herself: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ym3tKiq6O4U&t=80s

@fez Thanks for the link - I've added this to my answer (didn't realise that the BBC uploads to YouTube as well as it's own platform).
